# How to get ENABLED Feed Tracking custom object fields

Tags: apex, soql, api, chatter-feed

How can I query (SOQL/APEX/API) the feed tracking custom object fields that has CHECKED ENABLE FEED TRACKING? I'm looking to get the ONLY fields that has FEED TRACKING.

As shown the screen shot below, I like to query to see if the `Age` or `Country` or `City` has enabled feed tracking, is that possible to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query against [FieldDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm) and utilize SOQL and the Tooling API.

To get fields that have **Field History** enabled, you can use *SOQL*.

```
SELECT QualifiedApiName FROM FieldDefinition 
WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account' AND IsFieldHistoryTracked = true
```

This will output all the fields that have field history enabled on the given object.

---

To get what the question is specifically asking for, fields enabled for **Feed tracking**, you need to use the *Tooling AP*I. This is within the `Metadata` field of FieldDefinition and is accessible if only one row is returned in the query.

Below is an endpoint tested in Workbench REST Explorer

```
/services/data/v48.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+Metadata+FROM+FieldDefinition+WHERE+EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName='Account'+AND+QualifiedApiName='Name'
```

The return looks like the following - what you care about is `trackFeedHistory`

```
{
  "size" : 1,
  "totalSize" : 1,
  "done" : true,
  "queryLocator" : null,
  "entityTypeName" : "FieldDefinition",
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "FieldDefinition",
      "url" : "/services/data/v48.0/tooling/sobjects/FieldDefinition/Account.Name"
    },
    "Metadata" : {
      "businessOwnerGroup" : null,
      ....//took out a bunch of fields
      "summaryOperation" : null,
      "trackFeedHistory" : true,
      "trackHistory" : true
    }
  } ]
}
```

Comment: good thought about the fieldDefinition, when I run the query I get the following error message `FieldDefinition: a filter on a reified column is required [EntityDefinitinId, DurableId]`

Comment: You got that error message with the query in my answer? I only get that error if I don't include EntityDefinition in my WHERE clause. You can't get all fields across all objects in one query - you have to specify.

Comment: +1 sorry, I did not copy and paste your query but it seems like working without error BUT this is strange even though I triple check that my custom object is enabled feed tracking and I have field checked but when I run the above query obviously changing the `qualified api name` to my custom object but I get 0 results. Any thoughts ?

Comment: I try to use `trackFeedHistory` and I get an error `No such column on the entity FieldDefinition`

Comment: I totally spaced. I just realized you're looking at feed tracking and I gave you field history. What you're looking for is within `Metadata` which is only available through the Tooling API (not SOQL query). Give me a second to edit

Comment: I think Feed Tracking is a specific type of Field History Tracking and many fields which have tracking enabled don't have the setting being asked about.

Comment: ah got it thanks Kris

Answer (score -1):

For feedtracking, Salesforce will create a new object which can be accessed by suffixing __Feed to your custom object. 
You try querying with object __Feed along with your Age, country & City fields.

Comment: I don't see any fields in that `__feed` object